# Setup log4j with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j

I had a normal project with barebones java. The original codebase used log4j for logging

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

I had to add `spring-boot-starter-websocket` to it.
My spring boot parent:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

To make it work with log4j, I had to exclude logback and add log4j dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I run the code, it says give this warning:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have yaml properties and log4j properties in `./config`.
[image]

I have different logger classes in my project which extends `FileAppender` and corresponding appenders in log4j.xml...

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="file-server" class="com.theglobalmarketaccess.anzfwk.utils.logging.DailyLogger">
        <param name="File" value="-S.txt"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value= "trace"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'dd-MM-yyyy'.txt.gz'"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p- %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1):

This occurs when the default configuration files log4j.properties and log4j.xml can not be found and the application performs no explicit configuration. log4j uses Thread.getContextClassLoader().getResource() to locate the default configuration files and does not directly check the file system. Knowing the appropriate location to place log4j.properties or log4j.xml requires understanding the search strategy of the class loader in use. log4j does not provide a default configuration since output to the console or to the file system may be prohibited in some environments.

Doc is here -> https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html,  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: It works when I place log4j.xml in resources directory. But I need to use config/log4j.xml for easy modification. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?? if you want to modifiy configuration there is the doc -> https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html